# Simplify $\frac{x - \sin(x)}{x^2}$ into a non-singular expression?

Tags: trigonometry

Is there a way to rewrite:

$$\frac{x - \sin(x)}{x^2}$$

with non-singular elementary functions, such as $sinc(x)$? By singular I mean that the above expression has a $1/x^2$ factor which by itself diverges. However the complete expression has a well-defined limit as $x\rightarrow 0$. Is there a way to rewrite this that makes the limit obvious?

For example, $\sin(x)/x$ can be written as $sinc(x)$, which has a well-defined value at $x=0$. Can something similar be done for the above expression?

Comment: Write $\sin x$ in Taylor series.

Comment: @Svetoslav I know how to write it as an infinite series. But is there an expression involving only special functions? You see, I want to compute this inside a computer program. An infinite series is a pain, and it wouldn't be good for the entire domain of $x$.

Comment: Aha, I understand :)

Comment: Then, why don't you just compute it with a conditional expression: if $x\neq 0$ then it is the above closed form, else you assign its limit at $x=0$. The closed form that you want will be just a continuous extension of this function from $\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$ to the whole $\mathbb R$

Comment: @Svetoslav For $x$ very small, it won't be accurate.

Comment: Yes, you are right !

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the graphic of the [**sinc** function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) is extremely close to that of the cosine function

around the origin, then write $~\dfrac{x-\sin x}{x^2}=\dfrac{1-\dfrac{\sin x}x}x\simeq\dfrac{1-\cos x}x=\dfrac{2\sin^2\dfrac x2}x~.~$ Can you

conclude ?

Comment: Of  course, $ = \sin(x/2) \textrm{sinc}(x/2)$. How accurate is this?

Comment: @becko: Around $x=0$, you mean ?

Comment: Yes, around $x=0$. I suppose I should use your approximation for $|x|<\delta$, and the original formula for $|x|\ge \delta$. How can I determine an optimal (or at least suboptimal but good) $\delta$? And thanks!

Comment: @becko: Why don't you just [plot](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) the difference of the two functions, and find out for yourself ?